# Paypal test accounts

Tags: paypal

I'm totally new to integrating Paypal in website.

In paypal test accounts **¿it's enough with -facilitator account for the seller and other account for the Buyer? Or I need to create another account for the seller?**
I mean: it's enough with 2 accounts ( -facilitator account for the seller and other personal account for the Buyer) or I need at least 3 ( -facilitator account for the seller, an other Business acount as Seller and an other personal account for the Buyer)

If I have to create another account for the seller: which API Credential I have to use? the one of -facilitator account or the other I have to create?
I have tried both, and it seems it goes ok with both...could that be possible?

Another question: reading the PayPal Documentation for Developers: 'Planning Your Test Accounts', I can't see which API is the best for my Prestashop website: **¿Merchant APIs versus Adaptive APIs?** 
By the moment, I am trying with the Standard Paypal and I think I have to use Merchant APIs, is this correct? My shop is a simple shop...
Thanks a lot,
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's enough with 2 accounts ( -facilitator account for the seller and other personal account for the Buyer) , facilitator account would be a business account when it is auto-created.

Basically, you will need a seller account(business) and a buyer account(personal) to test your PayPal transactions in Sandbox(Test Environment).

**Classic and REST API:**

Adaptive API's are used for Adaptive payments which involves(single,chain,parallel payment etc)

I would suppose that you could use [Classic API's](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/) in your Prestashop site.

Comment: Thanks very much Vimal! that clarify me

Comment: Glad it clarifies, you could accept the answer if it was helpful. :)